# Extend get_month_day_range() method

Tags: python

Is there a way to extend `get_month_day_range()` function   with `week` and `year` in addition to month?

The method could be define as `get_day_range(period, date)` which period could be either `week`, `month` or `year`.

```
import datetime

# requires python-dateutil (http://labix.org/python-dateutil)
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get_month_day_range(date):
    """
    For a date 'date' returns the start and end date for the month of 'date'.

    Month with 31 days:
    >>> date = datetime.date(2011, 7, 27)
    >>> get_month_day_range(date)
    (datetime.date(2011, 7, 1), datetime.date(2011, 7, 31))

    Month with 28 days:
    >>> date = datetime.date(2011, 2, 15)
    >>> get_month_day_range(date)
    (datetime.date(2011, 2, 1), datetime.date(2011, 2, 28))
    """
    last_day = date + relativedelta(day=1, months=+1, days=-1)
    first_day = date + relativedelta(day=1)
    return first_day, last_day

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

### UPDATE

The @cricket_007 work OK, but not all the time. It is not working with `week` for `datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 10)` and with `year` for `datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 5)`. How could I fix it?

Comment: The answer to the question is yes. Now, is there at attempted solution, you would like to show?

Comment: Thanks for your update @cricket_007. To answer your answer, I am not even sure how to start to do this. I didn't try a lot of thing so far.

Comment: Well, you already stated `get_day_range(period, date)`, so start with `if period == 'week'` ...

Comment: Given that relativedelta accepts days and weeks, how would that be different that using months?

Comment: That delta class accepts weeks and years. http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html#dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta

Comment: With week, I would like it could give me the beginning and the end of the week. If the date is `datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26`), then the method will give me `(datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 24), datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 30))`. The same principle will be apply with year.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this

```
def get_period_day_range(date, period='month'):
    last_day = None
    first_day = date + relativedelta(day=1)

    if period == 'month':
        last_day = date + relativedelta(day=1, months=1, days=-1)
    elif period == 'week':
        last_day = date + relativedelta(day=1, weeks=1, days=-1)
    elif period == 'year':
        last_day = date + relativedelta(day=1, years=1, days=-1)
    return first_day, last_day
```

The "week" logic doesn't really apply that well to `day=1`, though. In other words, you'll need to somehow determine where the "start" of the given date's week is